Embedding Direct sum of Tensor Products Into a Single Tensor Product
I am reading an article that states the following:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with decomposition $(H_j)_j$ of mutually orthogonal Hilbert subspaces and $A$ a $C^{*}$-algebra.  Then there exists a natural faithful $*$-homomorphism: $$\iota:\bigoplus^{c_0}_{j \in J} A \otimes K(H_j) \hookrightarrow A \otimes K(H)$$ such that $\iota \circ \iota_j = \text{id}_A \otimes \pi_j$ where $\iota_j: A \otimes K(H_j) \hookrightarrow \bigoplus^{c_0}_{j \in J} A \otimes K(H_j)$ is the obvious embedding and $\pi_j: K(H_j) \hookrightarrow K(H)$ by sending $x$ to $\hat{x}$ where $\hat{x}|_{H_j} = x$ and $\hat{x}|_{H^{\perp}_j} = 0$.

Now it's obvious to me that $\bigoplus^{c_0}_{j \in J} K(H_j) \hookrightarrow K(H)$ by $\pi = \bigoplus_{j \in J} \pi_j$ so we have an obvious embedding: $$\text{id}_A \otimes \pi: A \otimes_{\min} \bigoplus^{c_0}_{j \in J} K(H_j) \hookrightarrow A \otimes K(H)$$ so to prove this claim, I need to find an embedding (or even better an isomorphism): $$??: \bigoplus^{c_0}_{j \in J} A \otimes K(H_j) \hookrightarrow A \otimes_{\min} \bigoplus^{c_0}_{j \in J} K(H_j)$$ but doing this seems elusive to me. I can't figure out what a term $(x_j)_j \in \bigoplus^{c_0}_{j \in J} A \otimes K(H_j)$ would be sent to, since there is only one copy of $A$ in the term $A \otimes_{\min} \bigoplus^{c_0}_{j \in J} K(H_j)$, especially since whatever this map would be, it has to be a $*$-homomorphism, and the multiplicativity part doesn't seem to be easily satisfied.
Alternatively, perhaps there is just a general theorem that says if $(B_j)_j$ is a family of $C^{*}$-algebras with $*$-homomorphisms $\pi_j: B_j \longrightarrow M(D)$ for $D$ another $C^{*}$-algebra, then there exists a unique $*$-homomorphism $\pi: \bigoplus^{c_0}_{j \in J} B_j \longrightarrow M(D)$ such that $\pi \circ \iota_j = \pi_j$?

It’s just sending $(x_j)_j$ to $\sum_j x_j$. The direct sum is $c_0$-direct sum, so the infinite sum is indeed in $A \otimes K(H)$.

The “general theorem” you’re suggesting is definitely false. You need $\pi_j(B_j)$ to be pairwise orthogonal, for example. (In fact, that’s the equivalent condition.)

Oh oops yeah, the sum converges because of that.

Yeah, and you can verify this is a $\ast$-homomorphism by just verifying on finitely supported sequences and then applying continuity.
